# Implement 2x2 rotation matrix in c#

Tags: c#, vector, matrix, rotational-matrices

I rotate a vector using the following code:

```
   var newVectorX = Math.Cos(step) * normalizedVector.X 
                                 - Math.Sin(step) * normalizedVector.Y;

                var newVectorY = - Math.Sin(step) * (normalizedVector.X )
                                 + Math.Cos(step) * normalizedVector.Y;
```

I tried to create a 2x2 matrix so I just can multiply my normalized vector with the matrix. The result would be the new rotated vector instead the coordinates.

[image: rotation matrix]

Unfortunately `System.Windows.Media.Matrix` doesn't support 2x2 matrices. I couldn't find any implementation of this rotation matrix so far. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [`System.Windows.Media.Matrix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.aspx) is exactly what you need. While it may seem that you want a 2x2 matrix, using a 3x3 matrix allows for translations too. Just use a `System.Windows.Media.Matrix` and ignore the part you don't need.

```
Matrix rotate = Matrix.Identity;
rotate.Rotate(step * 180 / Math.PI);    // Rotate() takes degrees
Vector newVector = rotate.Transform(normalizedVector);
```

Comment: Matrix.Identity.Rotate doesn't return a Matrix

Comment: For solution see my comment above

Comment: Yes, I moved the Rotate step to be a separate statement. And I fixed the conversion to degrees.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that. I hope one man crew understands I have to accept this answer since it's the implementation I was looking for.